# Is OpenSSH appropriate for encrypting large amounts (MB/GB) of data?

Tags: openssl, openssh

I've written a backup script on my linux machine that creates periodic archives of my work folders, then uploads them to a couple of different servers. As some of the files contain sensitive information I want to be able to encrypt these backups. I already have the code that creates the archives and uploads them, however I need to know the best way to encrypt the file and what the relevant command would be.

I already have an OpenSSH key with a pass phrase. My understanding is that I should encrypt the file with my public key located in (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub). Then if I have to download the file I will use my private key and passphrase to decrypt it.

Is my understand correct? Should I be using my OpenSSH key for this? What would be the appropriate command to use to encrypt my file?

If it's relevant, the backup script runs everyday and extracting of the back would happen very infrequently.

Answer (score 2):

No, SSH is not the right tool for that as it is a transmission protocol.

What you are looking for is [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy). See also [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Well *if* you are willing to use "stable beta" software, there's [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

The big plus here is that works like `rsync` so you should minimize the amount of data transferred every day while still encrypting your data.

Comment: hey thats pretty nice :) yeah i cant think of anything else that does that on the fly, i suppose the equivalent would be mounting LUKS disks on your server and writing over SSH / rsync to them. this is a more elegant solution though...